# A simple Jquery GET and POST not calling PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, post, get, httprequest

I am new to web development, and have encountered a problem with jquery and php. Having trouble calling a php file with jquery through xampp using a simple GET and POST a http request. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
<?php
    $name=$_POST['name'];

    if($_POST['name']!=""){
        echo 'Shalom'.$name;
    }else{
        echo 'Enter name';
    }
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
    <button id="button">Submit</button>
    <div class="response"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#button').click(function(){

            var name=$('#name').val();
            $.post('jquery post http request.php',{name:name},function(response,status,xhr){
            $('.response').text(response);
        });
       });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Ok fair enough. So OP has done that and also changed the name parameter. Code _looks_ like it should work (aside from the strange URL, which I assumed was just for demonstration or something).

Comment: Doyle, do you still have any issues with this?

Comment: possibly `'jquery post http request.php'` is not the correct filename

Comment: I am still having issues, and not sure what I am doing wrong. I edited the code snippets. The url is just a local php file I made.